# How can I prevent django from opening another window upon hitting the login button on the login page?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-authentication

I am coding a small web app using django (version 3.0) and python (version 3.7.1). I use django's integrated authentification tool to manage user login and such things. The problem I am facing is, that when I log in with any user I get redirected to the next page, as I want it, but it does open in a new browser window and that is not something I want to happen. Since I do not know where to start fixing this issue I can not provide any information about what I already tried. But it only happens when I pass any next parameter to the login form (e.g. account/login?next=/general_information/ to get redirected to the general information page after successful login. It happens with any redirect url.)

## **EDIT**

## Login Template

```
{% extends 'fehlzeit/base.html' %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% block title %}
        <title>FEHLZEIT || LOGIN</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block main %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="margin-left: 59.3%; width: 100%; color: red;">Benutzername und Passwort stimmen nicht überein!</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="login_form">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                    <caption class="main_title" style="text-align: center; border-radius: 4px">Login</caption>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Benutzername</td>
                        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Passwort</td>
                        <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button type="submit">Einloggen</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
            </form>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={% url 'fehlzeit:home' %}" />
    {% endif %}
{%  endblock %}
{% block datetime_panel %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The login view is the preinstalled one of django 3.0.

Comment: Have you tried another browsers?

Comment: Post your code ...